# document.getElementsByName not working in IE11 but working good in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In IE11 document.getElementsByName is not working as expected.

```
var colRadioButtonSelected = document.getElementsByName("radioButtonSelected_" + containerCurrencyCode);

var colLabelNetDollarsDue = document.getElementsByName("labelNetDollarsDue_" + containerCurrencyCode);

var colLabelUSDAmount = document.getElementsByName("labelUSDAmount_" + containerCurrencyCode); 
            for(var x=0; x < colRadioButtonSelected.length; x++)
            {      
                colRadioButtonSelected[x].disabled = readOnly ? "disabled" : ""; 
                var textNetDollarsDue = colLabelNetDollarsDue[x].innerText;
```

Have debugged the code and seen document.getElementsByName section is returning different type of value in IE versions.

[image]

Have tried a Wrapper like below but didn't worked for me . Any Help?

```
function getElementsByNameWrapper(name) {
  a = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(name).length; ++i) {
    a.push(document.getElementsByName(name)[i]);
  }

  return a;
}
```

Have changed to

```
var textNetDollarsDue = colLabelNetDollarsDue[x].textContent ||
    colLabelNetDollarsDue[x].innerText;
```

Error looks like

[image]

HTML markup is something like below ..

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ReportRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ReportRepeater_ItemDataBound">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <tr class="<%# OddEven("odd", "even") %>">
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="radio" id="radioButtonSelected_<%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).BaseCurrency %>" name="radioButtonSelected_<%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).BaseCurrency %>" disabled="disabled" style="visibility: <%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).SecurityNumber) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).CusipNumber)) ? "hidden" : "" %>;" value="<%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).IncomeReportId %>" /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).IncomeStatus %></td>
                                                    <td align="left"><%# String.Format("{0:d}", ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).AllocationDate) %></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).SedolNumber %></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).IsinNumber %></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).ReportEvent %></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).ReferenceNumber %></td>
                                                    <td align="left"><%# String.Format("{0:d}", ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).RecDate) %></td>
                                                    <td align="left"><label id="labelPayDate_<%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).BaseCurrency %>"><%# String.Format("{0:d}", ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).PayDate) %></label></td>
                                                    <td align="right"><%# String.Format("{0:#,##}",((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).Quantity) %></td>
                                                    <td align="right"><%#  ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).BaseRate %></td>
                                                    <td align="right"><label id="labelNetDollarsDue_<%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).BaseCurrency %>"><%# Formatting.FormatCurrency(((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).NetDollarsDue).Replace("$","")%></label></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><label id="labelUSDAmount_<%# ((ReportEntity)Container.DataItem).BaseCurrency %>"></label></td>
                                                    <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td style="width:120px" align="center"><a id="Details" runat="server" >Show Details</a></td>                                    
                                                </tr>
```

Comment: Do you have `name`s or `id`s in the elements?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting different results, but declare "a" with `var` and call `.getElementsByName()` just once, saving the result.

Comment: @Teemu- I have Id,ClassName,Name,TagName,TagNameNS for this element

Comment: What are those elements? `name` is deprecated except in window objects and form elements. I noticed just few days ago, that `div`s with `name`s are not collected by `gEBN()` in IE11 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `.getElementsByName()`. The issue is that IE11 supports the standard `.textContent` instead of the old (non-standard) `.innerText`.

You can account for either version like this:

```
 var textNetDollarsDue = colLabelNetDollarsDue[x].textContent ||
    colLabelNetDollarsDue[x].innerText;
```

*edit* — the above is sort-of true (though IE11 may still understand `.innerText`) but with your markup posted it's now clear that the problem is that you're using the `ByName()` API but you're really interested in "id" values. You can use a class name instead of an "id" for those labels; the markup is invalid with all those duplicated "id" values anyway.

Comment: It's not working as colLabelNetDollarsDue has a length of Zero in IE11..Not sure why it's happening..Have editrd my question with that error

Comment: I'm pretty sure IE11 supports both.

Comment: @RahulChowdhury well what does your HTML markup look like?

Comment: @RahulChowdhury you're using `getElementsByName()` to fetch elements *by their "id" values*.  That's what's different between IE8 and IE11.

Comment: @Pointy - Have tried with getElementById but no luck. I even surprised getElementsByName() is working good in IE8

Comment: @RahulChowdhury "id" values must be unique; `getElementById()` only returns one element. IE8 was badly behaved and implemented `.getElementsByName()` improperly; it's not supposed to pay attention to "id" values.